# Can't specify SDK in Intellij on Linux

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.6 Pro on a Linux (Ubuntu) machine and, it will not let me select an SDK for any Java project.

Whenever I start up the program and go to "Create a New Project" Java has no SDKs available. If go to new and try to specify where my JDKs are installed (I have a few) it always fails with the same error:
[image: Error Message]

I've tried specifying the locations:

- /usr/lib/jvm/
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
- /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/
- /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/
- /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

(these last three are all just symlinks)

I know I have a JDK installed for my default Java version. I can compile and run code via command line:

```sh
justin@stephanie:~/temp$ ls
HelloWorld.java
justin@stephanie:~/temp$ javac HelloWorld.java 
justin@stephanie:~/temp$ ls
HelloWorld.class  HelloWorld.java
justin@stephanie:~/temp$ java HelloWorld
Hello, World!
```

The output of `readlink -f $(which java)` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` (same location for `javac` exectuable).

Everything I've looked at online suggest that I should just be able to select `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` as my Java SDK but it is failing. I feel like I must be misunderstanding something essential here as I don't know why this isn't working.

Any help would be useful, I've never used IntelliJ before (I've always been an Eclipse user) and it is very frustrating I can't even create a project in it after a couple hours of trying to mess around with it.

Comment: Please try newer IDE version 2019 or 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Please try first with a [newer version of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/idea/download/#section=linux), preferably the most current one (currently this is 2020.2)

**2.** I had the same problem (with version 2020.2 on my Kubuntu system) and fixed it by simply [downloading and installing the SDK via IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk).

Comment: I never did get this working in Intellij 2017 and buying the 2020 version was the solution. A bit frustrating as I owned the 2017 version already but I encountered no issues when I upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr` directory is [mounted](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html) at `/var/run/host`.

You should find your jdk under `/var/run/host/usr/lib/jvm`.